# Get current route/path deliver _internal route

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm rendering data from a CMS via Twigcode to a Controller and the Controller renders a twig template. I'd like to have the current route. I already tried to use:

```
// Controller
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeName = $request->get('_route');

// or Twigtemplate
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

But the result is "_internal". How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the call to the Twig `path` function in your Twig template!

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}
```

instead of

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: im getting an Exception: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The "_internal" route has some missing mandatory parameters ("controller", "path", "_format").")

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2#comment14132455_7777229 . I guess your template is rendered in the standalone mode.

Comment: sorry im not using the standalone mode :(

Comment: Do you use this method in the main template or is an included templae? In that case, do you use {% render(...) %} or {% include(...) %}?

Comment: I use that statement in the main twig template the template is call by the symfony render statement in a COntroller

Comment: Hum, I don't have a clue now... Which version of Symfony do you use? If you can give some code extracts of your controller, that might help.