# preg_match in twig

Tags: php, twig

First of all, I know that the logic should be in the controller and not in the view and I keep it that way.

But in this particular situation I need to use preg_match within a ternary operation to set the css class of a div.

Example:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <div class="{{ (preg_match(list.a, b))>0 ? something : else }}"...>...</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I achieve the **(preg_match(list.a,b))>0** condition in twig?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2/44357061#44357061

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `preg_match()` directly but there are ways to accomplish it:

1. if your `list` is an entity, add a method `matches()`: `{{ (list.matches(b)) ? something : else }}`
2. you could create a custom Twig extension function that uses `preg_match()` internally http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 6):

For those who came here from Google search results (like me).

There's [containment operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator) that allows you to do something like this:

`{{ 'cd' in 'abcde' }} {# returns true #}`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from Serge's comment and is the correct answer.

In my example my string is "Message Taken - 12456756". I can then use |split to convert it into an array and use |replace to get ride of white space.

```
{% set mt = 'Message Taken' in d.note %}
{% if mt == true %}
   {#.. you can then do something that is true#}
   {% set mt_array = d.note|split('-') %}
   {{ mt_array[0] }} | {{ mt_array[1]|replace({' ' : ''}) }}
{% endif %}
```

This would output my string but I now control two parts instead of 1.