# Symfony2 Annotation find every useage

Tags: symfony, annotations, customization

I'm currently working on a custom Annotation for controller actions, and I'm struggling with one problem:
I currently can catch an event if the currently executed action uses this annotation, but what I really need is to find out which controllers use my annotation and use this data in a custom controller.

I couldn't find anything about this topic, has anybody some tipps for me?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2) will be usefull for you?

Comment: I've managed to access the routes, but now i'm left with strings like "web_profiler.controller.profiler:importAction"... I can't access my annotation that way...

what I'm trying to do is have a controller, that outputs a list of all the urls from controller methods, where my annotation is set...