# Switch template depending on the routing annotation

Tags: symfony, routes

I have following method in Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/add", name="item_add")
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="item_edit")
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Item $item = null)
```

This method loads `edit.html.twig` template because of action name.

Is it possible to force using `add.html.twig` template if `item_add` route is matched and `edit.html.twig` if `item_edit` is matched ?

Comment: Why would you combine two different behaviors `("GET", "PUT")` in a single route? If you want to reuse your templating, what's wrong with [`extending`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) your views?

Comment: @Touki Because the logic of get and put actions is the same.

Comment: If they are the same, then you can create a second route `public function editAction(Request $request) { return $this->addAction($request); }` and keep your annotations

Comment: @Touki You're right, however I was thikink about maximal simplicity of the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by jperovic seems correct however, IMHO, using the route name doesn't feel right.
Relying on the route name can be avoided with ease.

Here's an example

```
/**
 * @Route("/add", name="item_add")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template
 */
public function addAction(Request $request, Item $item = null)
{
    if (null === $item) {
        $item = new Item;
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType, $item, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('item_update'), // In your view?
        'method' => 'POST'
    ]);

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}

/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="item_edit")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Item $item)
{
    return $this->addAction($request, $item);
}
```

With this, you will have two routes doing almost same thing, and sending the same parameters

```
/edit/{id} => edit.html.twig
/add       => add.html.twig
```

Comment: Yes, your example makes perfect sense... :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is. `tuxedo25` explained it how here: [How to get current route in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2)

Basically:

```
$routeName = $request->get('_route');
if ( $routeName == "item_add"){
    // render template "add.html.twig"
}else{
    // render template "edit.html.twig"
}
```

Hope this helps...

---

**Idea #1:**

If you want to use `@Template` you could still keep the annotation as usual but you would:

```
return array(
            'route_name' => $routeName,
            // some other data
            );
```

Then:

<kbd>item.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% include routeName == 'item_add' ? 'item_add.html.twig' : 'item_edit.html.twig' %}
```

**Nevertheless, while this solves the issue, I feel like it's very cumbersome.** Personally I would never go this way.

---

**Idea #2:**

This idea takes whole different angle. While it does not use `@Template` it minimizes the possibility of error:

```
/**
 * @Route("/add", name="item_add")
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="item_edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Item $item = null){
    $routeName = $request->get('_route');

    # Your controller's logic here

    return $this->renderView(sprintf('VendorNamespaceBundle:ControllerClass:%s.html.twig', $routeName), aray(... your data here ... ));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without manually rendering template - just stil using `@Template` annotation ?

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. I have an idea on how to overcome this... updating the answer now...