# find out information about called controller from app.php in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am looking through properties of `$kernel`, `$loader`, `$request` and `$response` but cannot find anything related to controller and action that were actually called as a result of accessing specific URL. Is there a way to find out this info inside `app.php`, without manual analysis of route configuration files?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2

Comment: As I understand, that question is about finding out current route from inside a specific controller. The problem is that `app.php` is not a controller of ordinary sense, and there is no `$this` there.

Comment: Why in app.php? You shall never edit

Comment: It is not intended to be used on production servers or elsewhere, just for educational purposes.

Comment: For educational purposes look at this documentation page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: You can use the console to get info about routes and controllers

Comment: All of this information should be available on the Request object