# How to get root route in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony so hopefully this is trivial
[How to get current route in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2)
does not work for me because it returns route of the current controller

i have root controller that calls twig template in which another controller is being created with `render url('_internal_main_navigation')` and if i call

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeName = $request->get('_route');
```

from the nested controller i get _internal_main_navigation not _home or whatever is the root route

how would i get the _home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out [How to get current route in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2) had the answer, just not the accepted one

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660777/711072 pointed me in the right direction

the trick is passing it through template to controller like

```
{% render url('_internal_main_navigation', { 'route': app.request.attributes.get('_route') }) %}
```

and then it can be accessed in controller like

```
$this->getRequest()->query->get('route');
```

in controller

Comment: you want to redirect to home page from twig template right

Comment: *i don't know how to link answers sorry for revision link* you have to click on or copy the **share** link below any answer.