# Getting current route twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to get the current route on twig , I used this two code but It fail always

Code 1:

```
 {% if app.request.get('_route') == 'my_route' %}
      //Do something
 {% endif %}
```

Code 2:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get == 'my_route' %}
      //Do something
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: What does `app.request.get('_route')` return? This should be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current route in Symfony 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo I dump it and it show 'null' ..

Comment: Can you show us how you are rendering your file from your controller?

Answer (score 6):

Use the "app_dev.php" at the end of your URL to debug and check what route is being used at the bottom. For example I show "route1" here:
[image: Debug showing route1]

Then in your twig template you can use something like this:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'route1' %}
    <h1>test</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I verified this works. I'm using Symfony3 though.

Maybe also try instead of "app.request.attributes.get()", try these:

- app.request.pathinfo
- app.request.uri

See if those work.

Also if the route is indeed **null**, try:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == '' %}
    <h1>test</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What does the route show as in the bottom left by the "@" sign?

Comment: Then did you try `{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'categories_index' %}` to see if that works?