# Symfony 2.8 how to get Route option

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-routing

With EventListener I use my lass TransactionListener. This class check permission for current url. Some URL are open. I check it by attribut "option" in routing.yml

For getting option on current route I use very slow method 
**$route = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($e->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route'));**

Do I have other opportunity to get option-datafrom current route? How to get fully route-object from current route name or request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current route in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096546/how-to-get-current-route-in-symfony-2)

Comment: No, this return only actual route, witch you can translate into url, but it is impossible get more information about route, like "option" parameters.